# Create links between mininet switches emulated on different machines

Tags: python, mininet, sdn

I need to break the network into parts and emulate each part on my Linux machine. For example, on machine No. 1 the following topology is launched:

```
    class MyTopology(Topo):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            s1 = self.addSwitch(name='s1', protocols='OpenFlow13', dpid='0000000000000001')
            h1 = self.addHost(name='h1', ip='1.2.3.1/24')
            s2 = self.addSwitch(name='s2', protocols='OpenFlow13', dpid='0000000000000002')
            self.addLink(s1, h1, delay='5ms')
            self.addLink(s1, s2, delay='5ms')
```

On machine No. 2 the following topology is launched:

```
    class MyTopology(Topo):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            s3 = self.addSwitch(name='s3', protocols='OpenFlow13', dpid='0000000000000003')
            s4 = self.addSwitch(name='s4', protocols='OpenFlow13', dpid='0000000000000004')
            self.addLink(s3, s4, delay='5ms')
```

I want to link the switches s1, s3 and s2, s3. To get the topology:

```
               +-----+
               |  h1 |
               +-----+
                 |
                 |
                 |
            +----+-----+
            |    s1    |
            +-----------+
           /             \
          /               \
     +----+----+          +----+----+
     |    s2   |----------|    s3   |
     +----+----+          +----+----+
                          /
                         /
            +-----------+
            |    s4    |
            +----+------+
```

I tried to do

```
    Intf('enp0s9', node=s1)
    Intf('enp0s9', node=s2)
```

by car No. 1.

```
    Intf('enp0s9', node=s3)
```

by car No. 2
machines are connected to a local network by the "enp0s9" interface, but when you try to attach one interface to two switches, they stop connecting to the controller.